# drupal - 2 sites 1 user table

Tags: php, drupal

I have 2 sites: xyz.com (just simple 2 links to sites), a.xyz.com (on drupal) and b.xyz.com (also on drupal). 
I want to make, that if somebody will create account on a.xyz.com, this account will also work on b.xyz.com (and on other side- from b.xyz.com to a.xyz.com). The same situation with login - if somebody will log in on a.xyz.com/b.xyz.com, this account will be active on b.xyz.com/a.xyz.com).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do with is with Drupal [Bakery](http://dgo.to/bakery) the SSO solution that's extremely robust and secure.

You may find the more light weight [Account Sync](http://dgo.to/account_sync) does what you need; however you should be aware of the tradeoffs, including security.